How to get the correctly formatted value from a Hotkey Box in AutoHotkey v2
I'm using AutoHotkey v2 to create a GUI where the user can select a hotkey using a Hotkey Box. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to capture the hotkey value in the desired format. Currently, the output of my code is "+F12", but I need it in the format "+{F12}" to use the value directly without needing to format it manually.
Here is a simplified example of my code:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

MyGui := Gui("-MinimizeBox -MaximizeBox", "Tools")

myHotkey := MyGui.Add("Hotkey", "vMyHotkey", "+F12")
myBtn := MyGui.Add("Button", "", "Show Hotkey")
myBtn.OnEvent("Click", SendHotkey)
MyGui.Show()

F12:: Reload

SendHotkey(*) {
    ToolTip(myHotkey.Value)
}

The problem is that myHotkey.Value returns +F12 instead of +{F12}. Is there a way to get the Hotkey Box value directly in the +{F12} format so I can reuse it without needing additional formatting?

Without any formatting, probably not.
